# DateAdd and date fields not working as a criteria for a query

Tags: date, ms-access, ms-access-2013

The query I am working on has worked before. I don't know the exact date since I inherited it when my co-worker left. Every time I run the query I get a "Data type Mismatch in criteria expression."

```
   SELECT Personnel.Badge, Personnel.First_Name, Personnel.Last_Name, Training.Course, DateAdd("m",[Cert_Duration],[Latest_Course_Date]) AS Cert_Expiration, Personnel.Reports_To
FROM Training INNER JOIN (Personnel INNER JOIN qry_Training_Log_Latest_Course ON Personnel.Badge = qry_Training_Log_Latest_Course.Personnel) ON Training.Training_ID = qry_Training_Log_Latest_Course.Course
WHERE (((DateAdd("m",[Cert_Duration],[Latest_Course_Date]))<DateAdd("m",6,Date())) AND ((Training.Cert_Duration) Is Not Null));
```

It appears the line

I would appreciate any feedback on this.

Comment: 1) are you sure it's the `DateAdd` function and Date Fields? 2) did any of the data types for the field change recently?

Comment: Is this change anything ? `SELECT Personnel.Badge, Personnel.First_Name, Personnel.Last_Name, Training.Course, DateAdd("m",[Cert_Duration],[Latest_Course_Date]) AS Cert_Expiration, Personnel.Reports_To
FROM ((Training 
   INNER JOIN Personnel  ON Training.Training_ID = qry_Training_Log_Latest_Course.Course)
   INNER JOIN qry_Training_Log_Latest_Course ON Personnel.Badge = qry_Training_Log_Latest_Course.Personnel)
WHERE (((DateAdd("m",[Cert_Duration],[Latest_Course_Date]))<DateAdd("m",6,Date())) AND ((Training.Cert_Duration) Is Not Null));`

Comment: When I tried using your code it was giving a join syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query also triggers *"Data type Mismatch in criteria expression."*

```sql
SELECT DateAdd("m", Null, Date());
```

Therefore your error is likely caused by Null `[Cert_Duration]` values in this expression ...

```sql
DateAdd("m",[Cert_Duration],[Latest_Course_Date])
```

You need to revise the query to either ...

1. Exclude rows with Null `[Cert_Duration]` values *before* the `DateAdd()` is evaluated.
2. Or substitute something else for Null `[Cert_Duration]` values in that expression.

Comment: HansUP, you were able to point me in the right direction. Luckily the category being referenced only has 6 entries so I was able to filter by Training.Training_ID. As soon as I did that, the query worked flawlessly.